# Как обратиться к конкретному элементу из нескольких с одинаковым классом в jQuery?

Tags: html, css, jquery

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.
Имеем несколько элементов с одинаковым классом. Например, .js-cardPrice.
Так: $('.js-cardPrice'); я получу их все сразу.
Как обратиться к тому, по которому кликнули?

```
 var addBasketEL = $('.js-btnBasket');
var selectedContainerEL = $('.js-selectedContainer');

// Cards Content
var cardImageEL = $('.js-cardImage');
var cardCategoryEL = $('.js-cardCategory');
var cardNameEL = $('.js-cardName');
var cardPriceEL = $('.js-cardPrice');

function addSelectedCard(e) {
e.append(`
 <article class="selected-card js-selectedCard">
   <div class="selected-card__image">
     ${cardImageEL.html()}
   </div>

   <div class="selected-card__text">
     <a href="#" class="cards__category">${cardCategoryEL.text()}</a>

     <h2 class="selected-card__name">
        ${cardNameEL.html()}
     </h2>
   </div>

   <span class="price selected-card__price">${cardPriceEL.text()}</span>

   <button class="btn__delete js-btnDelete"></button>
 </article>
 `);
}

// Program Execution
$(function () {
addBasketEL.click(function () {
 if (selectedContainerEL.length) {
   $('.js-selectedCard').remove();

   $('button').removeClass('active');

   addSelectedCard(selectedContainerEL);

   $(this).addClass('active');
 } else {
   addSelectedCard(selectedContainerEL);

   $(this).addClass('active');
 }

 $('.js-btnDelete').click(function () {
   $(this).parent().remove();
 });
});
});
```

[Ссылка на codepen:](https://codepen.io/iliyasold/pen/GRKLdMW)

Comment: Где обратиться, внутри функции обработчика события? Вы уже это делаете через $(this).

Comment: У вас объявлено событие `$('.js-btnDelete').click`, таким же образом вы можете объявить клик и на `.js-cardPrice` в чем проблема? Если вы хотите узнать по какому элементу был клик нужно использовать `$(this).` как написал выше Gonzo.

Comment: "Где обратиться, внутри функции обработчика события? Вы уже это делаете через $(this)." - да, но $(this) - это сама кнопка, а мне нужно обратиться к элементам карточки, в которой она находится. Как это сделать?

Comment: "$(this) - это сама кнопка, а мне нужно обратиться к элементам карточки, в которой она находится" - у вас уже есть отправная точка, т.е. кнопка по которой кликнули ($(this)). Если вам нужна любая информация лежащая рядом именно с этой (нажатой) кнопкой, то вы можете воспользоваться навигацией по DOM дереву, относительной этой кнопки, любым удобным для вас способом ( .parent(), .parents(), .siblings(), .find(), что угодно ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короче, всего-то навсего нужно было спокойно и без суеты пройти по дому в нужном направлении, типа так: ${$(this).parent().parent().parent().find(cardNameEL).text()}, ну и причесать это все в переменные, конечно.
Благодарю всех, кто откликнулся!

Comment: Вместо кучи `.parent` можно написать один `.closest('.parent')` (где `.parent` - элемент | подробнее о [`.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/closest))

Comment: Это да, согласен.

Answer (score 0):

В обработчике, допустим как у нас `$().on('click')`, `$(this)` - это тот самый элемент, в котором сработал обработчик.
Т.е., конкретно в этом примере, это тот, на который кликнули.

```js
$('.js-cardPrice').on('click', function(){      
  $(this).toggleClass('toggle');
  let index = $(this).index();
  console.info(`Вы нажали на ${index}й элемент`);
});
```

```css
.js-cardPrice {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.js-cardPrice.toggle {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="js-cardPrice"></div>
<div class="js-cardPrice"></div>
<div class="js-cardPrice"></div>
<div class="js-cardPrice"></div>
<div class="js-cardPrice"></div>
<div class="js-cardPrice"></div>
```

> ..а мне нужно обратиться к элементам карточки, в которой она находится..

Для этого используйте, например [`.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

```js
$('.js-cardPrice').on('click', function() {
  let level = $(this).closest('.level'),
      indexLevel = level.index(),
      indexCard = $(this).index()+1;
      
  level.toggleClass('toggle');
      
  console.info(`Вы нажали на ${indexCard}й элемент, ${indexLevel}го уровня`);
});
```

```css
.level {
  font-size: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 110px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.js-cardPrice {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.js-cardPrice:nth-child(1) {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.level.toggle {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="level">
  <div class="js-cardPrice"></div>
  <div class="js-cardPrice"></div>
</div>
<div class="level">
  <div class="js-cardPrice"></div>
  <div class="js-cardPrice"></div>
</div>
<div class="level">
  <div class="js-cardPrice"></div>
  <div class="js-cardPrice"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Все верно, но мне нужно получить содержимое не того элемента, по которому кликнули, а элементов, которые находятся в той же карточке, в которой кнопка размещена и таких карточек может быть много. У них одинаковые классы и, когда я обращаюсь, допустим: к ${cardImageEL.html()} чтобы получить html-содержимое, получаю все cardImageEL, а мне нужно только содержимое конкретной карточки, по кнопке которой кликнули. Как это сделать?

Comment: Я дополнил ответ, посмотрите ниже

Comment: Я пробовал с .closest(), но, почему-то получаю undefined..((

Comment: Не могу понять никак - почему так происходит..

Comment: @CblPok2513 Что тут не так:
${$(this).closest(cardImageEL).html()} ..?

Comment: Что содержит в себе переменна `cardImageEL`?

Comment: Спасибо, я уже разобрался (написал выше комментарий). Благодарю!